# How transparent should questions with ignored tags be?

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface, ignored-tags

Inspired by [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/questions-with-ignored-tags-are-a-little-too-transparent), I actually rather thought of the opposite - to make ignored questions even more transparent. Currently, they are visible enough so it becomes a bit difficult to distinguish between ignored and not-ignored ones. At least for me.

My personal workaround was to check "Hide ignored tags", but that leads to weird "bugs" (undesirable behavior that is, I was told, by design).

I'm not sure how this issue should be solved. Apparently opinions differentiate quite a lot here, and customization like a slider controlling transparency are definitely overkill (and maybe not even possible to implement).

Answer (score 1):

I've added a little styling of my own via Firefox's [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) extension:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("http://stackoverflow.com/questions") {
  div.tagged-ignored a {
    color: #666666 !important;
  }
  div.tagged-ignored div.excerpt,
  div.tagged-ignored div.views {
    display: none !important;
  }
  div.tagged-ignored div.stats {
    font-size: 40% !important;
  }
  div.tagged-ignored div.stats div.status,
  div.tagged-ignored div.stats div.status strong {
    background-color: #EEEEEE !important;
    color: #555555 !important;
  }
}
```

This results in a shrunk and faded ignored question—but not completely gone.